# Exploding array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a script that connects to a server using proxies, going through the list until it finds a working proxy.

The list of proxies is like this:

```
127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1:8080
```

Of course, it's not the same IP and port over and over. Now, originally I was just going to use `file()` to put them all into an array, but that leaves an array with the values including the full line, obviously.

Ideally what I'd like is an array like

```
"127.0.0.1" => 8080,
"127.0.0.1" => 8080,
"127.0.0.1" => 8080,
"127.0.0.1" => 8080,
"127.0.0.1" => 8080,
"127.0.0.1" => 8080,
"127.0.0.1" => 8080,
"127.0.0.1" => 8080,
```

But I'm not sure of the easiest (and most efficient) way to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over the file and do some parsing:

```
$path = './file.txt';

$proxies = array();
foreach(file($path, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
  $proxy = trim($line);
  list($ip, $port) = explode(':', $proxy);

  $proxies[$ip] = $port;
}

var_dump($proxies);
```

Should note that your 'expected' example is invalid array notation as the key is the same for every element. But I just assumed you were going for formatting.

Comment: You can also add `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` to the `file()` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Definitely seems a lot better than the hackjob I was going to do. Also, was my question really so bad that people had to downvote it? :/ -- Dang. Can't accept your answer for another 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code

```
<?php

$data = "127.0.0.1:8080
    127.0.0.1:8080
    127.0.0.1:8080
    127.0.0.1:8080
    127.0.0.1:8080
    127.0.0.1:8080
    127.0.0.1:8080";


    $urls = explode("\n",$data);

    $new_data = array();
    foreach($urls as $url){
        if($url!=""){
            $url_parts = explode(":",$url);
            $new_data[] = array($url_parts[0]=>$url_parts[1]);
        }
    }

    print_r($new_data);




?>
```